# Meaning of " trapping "?

Tags: meaning

This is the passage I'm reading:

> Using this
> method—and both human and inhuman
> spirits can do this—the entity bypasses
> the physical eye and projects the desired image directly to the ‘mind’s eye,’ or
> third eye as it’s called in Eastern
> religions. The result of this telepathic
> transfer of vibrations from one
> intelligence to another may have all the
> **trappings** of a physical being. In reality,
> however, the spirit may never have
> physically manifested at all One way or
> the other, though, something has to be
> there to be perceived.

This word doesn't really make sense to me and i can't understand it in this passage.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have , but unfortunately I couldn't understand. I'm looking for a synonym for it or a simple explanation

Comment: Please give the source for your quote.

Comment: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/trappings

Comment: To be fair, dictionary definitions may not be very helpful in this context because they concentrate on the sense [trappings of wealth](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/trappings). In this passage it just means _characteristic signs_.

Comment: @KateBunting I was about to VTC, but then wrote my answer for that very reason.

Comment: Thank you @KateBunting

Comment: @HotLicks it's from " The Demonologist: The Extraordinary Career of Ed and Lorraine Warren "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the meanings of 'trappings' is:

> conventional adornment; **characteristic signs**:
> *trappings of democracy.*
> <sup>[source](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/trappings)</sup>

In the passage that you quote, "*have all the trappings*" is synonymous to 'have the appearance'.